# Синоним без "не" к наречию "нескладно"

Tags: синонимы, наречия

Какой синоним без "не" можно подобрать к слову "нескладно"?

Answer (score 3):

Набираете в Яндексе: "нескладно синонимы". Один из ответов:

[https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/93999/нескладно](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/93999/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE)

мешковато, некрасиво, неудачно, неуклюже, вразлад, и т.д.

Выбираете подходящий вариант: **неуклюже, мешковато.** Слова, которые не употребляются без НЕ, тоже подходят для проверки.